# Authentication failure trying to upload Vimeo video

Tags: php, vimeo, vimeo-api

Using the official Vimeo PHP Library (https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php)

Attempting to upload a video using the `upload()` method of the client library return the following http response:

> The authentication token is missing a user ID and must be provided when uploading a video.

However the Client Id, Client Secret, and Token are all being set on the client before calling the `upload()` method:

Client initialization:

```
$this->setClient(new Vimeo($this->clientId, $this->clientSecret, $this->token));
```

Call to upload method:

```
     try{
        $videoUri = $this->getClient()->upload($path, [
            'name' => $name,
            'privacy' => [
                'view' => 'anybody'
            ]
        ]);
        return $videoUri;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        dump($e);
        return false;
    }
```

There is a tutorial endpoint, which I called using the client created above and got the following response:

```
{
    "message": "Success! You just interacted with the Vimeo API. Your dev environment is configured correctly, and the client ID, client secret, and access token that you provided are all working fine.",
    "next_steps_link": "https://developer.vimeo.com/api/guides/videos/upload",
    "token_is_authenticated": false
}
```

Any suggestions welcomed!

Comment: clientId is not the same as userId though. clientId and clientSecret are for the API app you created so users can authenticate. I guess `upload()` requires a user to be authenticated with your app https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php#authenticated

Comment: The intention is to upload to the account that the app belongs to rather than an authenticated users account

Comment: No clue, sorry. There's an upload example at https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php/blob/master/example/upload.php though, see if that helps in any way

Comment: That's the instructions I was following! 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the the token being used was an unauthenticated token. I'd made the assumption that you only needed an authenticated token to upload on behalf of another user. By generating a new authenticated token that had the 'upload' scope I was able to upload the video using the exact code posted above.

Answer (score 1):

The token you are generating is unauthenticated, meaning it can only read metadata public on vimeo.com -- it cannot be used to upload, retrieve data, or perform other actions on an account.

The giveaway is in the last line of the /tutorials response:

```
"token_is_authenticated": false
```

Take a look at the authentication docs on the Vimeo Developer Site here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication#understanding-auth-workflows

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - figured this out as you can see in my answer :)

Comment: @PiX06 You're welcome! Didn't notice your response until after I answered :)